# OpenGL ES 3 on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Does iOS 6 or iOS 7 support openGL ES 3.0 or it support only 2.0? I cann't find a defenite answer, but Apple documentation tell only about 1.1 and 2.0 versions

Comment: iOS7 is under NDA, don't discuss it on SO, rather ask in Apple developer forum.

Comment: GLES3 exists on iOS 7.0+ and you can use it only in the simulator or the just announced iPhone 5S. You just need to change context creation to :
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3];